# Helicopter blade centrifugal force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, centrifugal-force

Quoting from Prof. Leishman's book on Helicopter aerodynamics, the centrifugal force acting along the blade is calculated as below.

[image]

My intuition is, not only the mass of the small blade element $dy$ is relevant here but also the section of the blade ahead of the blade element $dy$ is important to taken in to account as shown in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b4mJ6-uphh0)

[image]

Because the book is highly regarded, there is no doubt it is correct, but I cannot wrap my head around as of why the section ahead of the blade element is omitted when calculating the centrifugal force. Could someone shed some light on this?

Also that derivation suggests the axial centrifugal force is 0 when $R$ is zero which is incorrect. the maximum centrifugal force should have been experienced at the hub.

Comment: Centrifugal force at distance $y$ from the hub is _not_ the same as tension in the blade at distance $y$. "Centrifugal force" only refers to the effect of the rotation on _a single particle_ at some specified distance from the center of the rotation. The tension at distance $y$ is going to include the sum of the centrifugal forces acting on _all_ of the particles that are further than $y$ from the center.

Comment: Thanks but my understanding is, Tension should be equal to CF at each section of the blade because otherwise part of the blade gonna fly away

Comment: Wikipedia says, [The magnitude of centrifugal force $F$ on an object of mass $m$ at the distance $r$ from the axis of rotation of a frame of reference rotating with angular velocity $\omega{}$ is $F=m\omega^2{}r$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_force) So by that definition, centrifugal force at the center, $r=0$, is zero. That's how it was taught to me in school. But notice formula 4.2 from your book, which is supposed to give what the author calls _total_ centrifugal force. It _integrates_ the Wikipedia formula from $0$ to $R$. In other words, it's adding up the centrifugal...

Comment: ...force on each particle of mass $m$ and radius $y$ to compute the total tension where the blade attaches to the hub.

Answer (score 0):

We would also have to take into consideration the tension force in the helicopter blade when the net force acting on the helicopter blade is asked.

Here, the derivation is only for the centrifugal force acting on the blade which doesn't include the force due to tension which is being calculated in the video.

In the images attached, $R$ hasn't been defined but I assume it to be the radius of the blade. When $R = 0$, The blade doesn't exist for any centrifugal force to act on it. Hence the centrifugal force would be 0.

If $R$ meant the distance of a $dm$ mass from the axis, $F_{CF} = dm \Omega^2 R$ and at $R=0$, $F_{CF} = 0$.

Comment: Sorry but this is basically what I mentioned in the question itself. My question is WHY only the CF of small blade element is taken into account instead of the correct CF experienced at distance R which is not (m*dr)*R*omega^2

Comment: the correct CF experienced at a distance $R$ is indeed $dm\Omega^2 E$